# Weird behaviour of nanosleep() in a loop

Tags: c, linux, loops

I was writing a simple C program, then I ran to a problem: when I put nanosleep() in a loop, my output is different from what I expect. The code is simple:

```
struct timespec ts = {1, 0};
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
      printf("test ");
      nanosleep(&ts,NULL);
    }
```

From what I understand, it should print word "test", then wait 1 second, repeat. However, when I run it, it waits for 4 seconds, and then it prints "test" four times, immediately. What confuses  me the most, is that the printing of each word should be done before sleeping, but it seems like it doesn't happen even in the first iteration of the loop. I realize that it may not be correct use of nanosleep() but in *man nanosleep* I couldn't find anything about not using it in loops.

Comment: Output buffering. Append a newline, or `fflush`.

Comment: Need to find a canonical dupe for this

Comment: There is some good information on this topic [here](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering).

Comment: This has nothing to do with nanosleep or loops.  Any long-running function will cause the behavior.